# md5 hash key for token value

Tags: string, hash, md5, token

Hello I need your help I've been working on this since yesterday with no success at all. I'm creating an MD5 string for token value but it's not passing at all below are the information.
Must be a hex-encoded MD5 HASH (32 digit hexadecimal number) of a concatenation of the following parameter values separated by”:” (values should be in lower case)

First, values should be converted to lower case:
Parameter: merchant_id value: test
Parameter: amount value: 15.25
Parameter: currency value: usd
Parameter: key value: alfa

Then their values are contacted:
test:15.25:aed:alfa

what I've did is the following codes:
a.
    md5($this->data['merchant_id'] . $this->data['amount'] . $this->data['currency'] . $this->data['key'])

b. `md5($this->data['merchant_id'] . ':; . $this->data['amount'] . ':; . $this->data['currency'] . ':; . $this->data['encryption_key'])`

c. `$hash  = $this->request->post['merchant_id'];
                $hash .= $this->request->post['amount'];
                $hash .= $this->request->post['currency'];
                $hash .= $this->request->post['key'];`

None of them is working can anybody help me please and thank you!

Comment: Yeah it's PHP it's an OpenCart module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using php. The first thing you can do is to use additional string variable to create the concatenated value:

```
$stringValue = $this->data['merchant_id'] . ':' . $this->data['amount'] . ':' 
    . $this->data['currency'] . ':' . $this->data['key'];
```

Check if it outputs the proper values (`echo $stringValue;`). If it's okay, then use md5:

```
$md5Value = md5($stringValue);
```

Comment: Yeah it's PHP it's an OpenCart module, what I need is to define the variables. Let show you what I mean

Usually the opencart variables are like that

$this->data['merchant_id']     = $this->config->get('merchant_id');
$this->data['key']     = $this->config->get('key');
$this->data['currency']        = $order_info['currency_code'];
$this->data['amount'] = $this->currency->format($order_info['total'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value'], false);

Comment: $this->data['ctoken']   = $this->data['merchant_id'] . ':' . $this->data['amount'] . ':' . $this->data['currency'] . ':' . $this->data['key'];;
  $md5Value = md5("$this->data['ctoken']");


What is need to show variables as below:

merchant_id = username
key     = key
amount     = 100.00 (without any symbols like USD or $) it should be only 100.00
currency    = usd (lower case)

Then do the md5 function to post the token

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do. Please clear it up a bit.